# Как работает Rich text Editor

Tags: java, android, edittext

Всем привет.
Приложение передаёт данные из EditText в базу на сервере и тут всё нормально, но теперь появилась задача реализовать в макете где есть несколько полей
EditText редактор текста для одного из полей макета.
Наткнулся в интернете на Rich text Editor и встал вопрос как его подключить, какой у него цикл и есть другие варианты редактора текста.
Наткнулся на исходники Rich text Editor вот с таким макетом:

```
<com.chinalwb.are.AREditor
    android:id="@+id/areditor"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    are:expandMode="MIN"
    are:hideToolbar="false"
    are:toolbarAlignment="BOTTOM"
    are:useEmoji="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    />.
```

И в классе:

```
private AREditor arEditor;
this.arEditor =  this.findViewById(R.id.areditor);
```

Кто сталкивался с такой задачей подскажите.
Как я понял надо подключить библиотеку, заменить свой `EditText` на `this.arEditor =  this.findViewById(R.id.areditor);`
И передать уже в `arEditor.setText(строка);`

Comment: Сталкивался неоднократно ... Надо вместо стандартного EditText подставить ArEditor ... А дальше - всё в обычном порядке ... Если-бы видеть все исходники вместе - это облегчило бы решение ...

Comment: @Filin Filin- вот по этой ссылке можно посмотреть исходник активности   (https://github.com/chinalwb/Android-Rich-text-Editor/blob/master/ARE/app/src/main/java/com/chinalwb/are/demo/ARE_MinBottomActivity.java). А эта ссылка на  build.gradle (https://github.com/chinalwb/Android-Rich-text-Editor/blob/master/ARE/app/build.gradle) .

Comment: @FilinFilin - действительно всё заработало как надо, правда на подключении модуля задержался, но в итоге всё стало понятным.  Оформите как ответ.

Comment: Я рад за Вас ... Удачи !